# How to use encryption in winrt, where you can encrypt strings to a specified length cipher text?

Tags: c#, azure, encryption, windows-runtime, uwp

I was creating a windows UWP application, Where I required some encryption of strings and inserting it into the azure table. I tried using `DataProtectionProvider.ProtectAsync()` method, which works fine except the encrypted string happens to become very large. I wanted a encryption where I can specify the length of the encrypted string. Or what are my alternatives here?

The operation I'm looking for is something of this sort

```
string encryptedText = encryptPlainText(plainText, password, encryptedTextSize);
```

Edit:
My requirements are:
I was trying to create something along the lines of a toDo app. I am using Azure Mobile Service with its Sync FrameWork just to be safe I wanted to use encryption on the data. But I know we can only save 64Kb of data in a single column hence I didn't want the encryption to take up most of that space. What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just arbitrarily set how long you want the ciphertext to be. It's going to be a function of how big the input is, plus any required padding, IV's, and signatures/MACs.

IIRC, for something like AES-GCM, you're going to have 28 bytes of additional expansion, 12 bytes for the IV, and 16 for the authentication tag. Additionally, you might want to Base64 encode the ciphertext, which will expand it by an additional factor of 4/3.

Not knowing anything about your requirements, you most likely don't want to be using the `DataProtectionProvider`. It's more flexible than the DAPI, but I think it still only encrypts using Active Directory credentials, or local user/computer accounts. The problem is, you might not be able to decrypt on a different machine, if it's protected under a local account.

You should instead post what your requirements are, so that people can offer better advice for what you're really trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've added the details of what I'm trying to achieve.